# Referencing a textfield from a cell in UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've created a tableview with five cells in Xcode 8. Each cell has its own label and textfield. I want to be able to access the user input from these textfields in a separate tableViewController file/class and then do stuff with the user input.

I've created a swift file/class for each cell. 
I've made each of the classes public. 
And, when creating the IBOutlet for each of the textfields, I've made those conform to the following format:

```
public class NameCell: UITableviewCell {

@IBOutlet public weak var NameTextField!

override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

override public func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

What I think I need to do is declare a variable in the viewcontroller class for the textfields in each class. I was wondering if this can be done? And if so, how do I declare the variables/textfields from another class? Or is there a better way?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
var NameTextField.NameCell = ""
```

Or

```
var NameCell.NameTextField = ""
```

But these are obviously wrong. I've also put the textfield delegate in the TableViewController class rather than the NameCell class. I don't know if this is contributing to the issue or not.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: First of all, you should not use uppercase for variable names. When is it that you need to access data from these cells? Is there any reason you prefer a UITableView instance and dequeueing cells instead of using a UIStackView/UIView?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @GrzegorzAperliński, I want to access the data after the user presses a "Done" barButton item. I initially used a simple view with textfields/labels etc and it worked fine. I thought using tableview might work better and look cleaner so wanted to know how it could be done.

Comment: Imho, tableViews should be used when dealing with tabular data, so that you can take advantage of the performance optimization given by cell reuse. If your form gets to long you can always place it in a UIScrollView. I find this approach less clunky than having to access subviews buy calling cellForRow

Comment: Yeah good point. Thank you again for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your IBOutlet variable is declared correctly. It should be:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: NameTextField!
```

Now, to access the text from the cell's `textField`, you first need to access the cell itself. You can call `var cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! NameCell` where `indexPath` is that of the cell you are attempting to access. Then, you can call `cell.textField.text`. This will give you the text that the user has entered into the `textField` of the given cell.

Also, make sure to read up on [swift basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) to understand the proper usage of variables and type annotations, as well as proper naming conventions.

Comment: Ok, yeah sorry I made a mistake when copying that IBOutlet over. I can see how the cell.textfield.text will work. But its throwing an error: Use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath'. Should I have put your suggestion in the cellForRowAt IndexPath function instead of outside any funcs/before viewDidLoad?

Comment: Nevermind, the indexPath error was something else. cellIdentifier.textfield.text is working a treat!